# Is this use of "complete with" idiomatic?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

"I’ve seen a Japanese brass band competition complete with the equipment in Youtube and the performance was simply great".

Is the use of "complete with" correct there?  Based on [this entry in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complete-with#:%7E:text=phrase,%2B%20with%5D), I'm not sure I'm using it in the right way:

> If one thing comes complete with another, it has that thing as an extra or additional part.
>
> *The diary comes complete with a gold-coloured ballpoint pen.*

Comment: It's grammatical but "complete with the equipment" is not clear in context. Do you mean the musical instruments?  Since it would be impossible to have a  brass band competition without the instruments, the reader wonders what you might mean.

Comment: If you're interested in how to use "complete with", it normally highlights something *quintessential*, emblemmatic of the perfect example, not something that is merely essential. "The circus came to town, *complete with fire-eaters and dancing elephants.*"

Comment: Please give a link to the source of this quote. Extra context really helps a lot. As it stands, there are other difficulties with the sentence (eg 'equipment in Youtube') as @TimR notes.

Comment: @Mitch, I make up my own example sentences.

Comment: And "perfect example" could mean "perfectly typical example". "The roadside diner was everything you'd expect, and nothing more. The scrambled eggs came *complete with two slices of buttered toast*."

Comment: @TimR I'm asking the OP to provide the source. If they're making it up then this proofreading and is off topic.

Comment: @Mitch: I've edited the question so it asks about the idiomatic use of a phrase. That is NOT proofreading.

Comment: @Mitch Proofreading is asking people to find and fix all the problems in a text. This is a question about how to use a specific phrase, it's fine for ELU or ELL.

Comment: Your sentence may make more sense when written as, "I’ve seen a Japanese brass band competition on YouTube, complete with trombones and trumpets, and the performance was great".

Comment: @Barmar The original title of this question was "Is my sentence correct? Please correct it. Thank you very much". 'Correct my text' is one of the few things I will close vote on (maybe good for [ELL.SE]?).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **complete with** sometimes indicates that an item has all essential parts:

> This vintage espresso machine comes complete with sight glass, which is often missing or broken. Bidding starts at $900.

But if something is often or almost always missing, then what is essential can take on the quality of being special.

The phrase can also highlight that the thing comes with something *quintessential*, emblemmatic of the perfect example, things the "average" or "less than ideal" example might lack:

> The circus came to town, complete with fire-eaters and dancing elephants.

Or it can mean that a thing is "perfectly typical" and in no way extraordinary:

> The roadside diner was everything you'd expect, and nothing more. The scrambled eggs came complete with two slices of buttered toast.

So the phrase can be used neutrally to state a fact *qua* fact, or rhetorically, and  the rhetorical uses can be  climactic or an anti-climactic.

Comment: But it also suggests that not having the item(s) doesn't preclude it from being acceptable. You can have a circus without elephants (some of the biggest circuses have recently stopped using them), but it's "better" with them.

Comment: @Barmar: Exactly, I was adding that as you were typing the comment.

Comment: Now we're even on upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

"comes complete with" is a set phrase that means "including", but implies that the items that are specified make the collection complete. It comes from this sense of the word from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/complete)

> B1: with all the parts

You can have a diary that doesn't come with a pen, but adding a pen completes the set.

It's not clear what you're trying to say in your example sentence about the band competition, so it's hard to tell whether you're using it correctly. If you explain what equipment you're referring to, I can add to the answer.

Comment: That is one of the meanings, so +1